# Talend Extract dynamic input and transpose it

Tags: java, talend, talend-mdm

I have an input flow with dynamic number of values in column :

678|32;29;29;46;48

094|2;8;9;9;48;48

the final result I need :

678|32

678|29

678|46

678|48

094|2

094|8

094|9

094|48

Should I use tjava to parse this flow and how to unpivot dynamically to rows?

Thanks

Comment: tJava is only for using with Talend? What you want can very easily be achieved with simple logic and some string splitting. What have you tried so far, was there any specific issues you had? Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @user6479259: Is `678|32;29;29;46;48` the string or `678` is the column and rest `32;29;29;46;48` is the row in column?

Comment: @sorifiend I can use other component also not only java but the tricky part is that  the second column is dynamic ans should be ransposed I tried to use tnormalizer but it's grouping by the first column.

Comment: @user6479259 678 is the first column and rest 32;29;29;46;48 is the second column to split ans to transpose

Comment: do you have TDM..

Answer (score 1):

I founed a Talend component that give me the right output, it is `tNormalize`

It take as input the column to normalise and split it dynamically and transpose the spitted values to rows.

thank you guys